# Randomized weighted majority with rational weights

Tags: algorithm-analysis, randomized-algorithms, online-algorithms

Consider the RWM online algorithm
as defined in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_weighted_majority_algorithm#Randomized_weighted_majority_algorithm_(RWMA));
this version is with multiplicative update.

Let us assume that we define our weights
as a fraction;
that is, $w_i^t = 1 / (M_i^t+c)$,
where $i$ is an expert,
$M_i^t$ is the number of mistakes
of expert $i$ until, and including, time $t$,
and $c$ is a positive constant.
By definition, $M_i^t = \sum_{i=1}^T m_i^t$,
where $m_i^t \in \{0,1\}$ indicates
whether expert $i$ makes a mistake at time $t$.
We also use $W^t$ to denote
the sum of weights at time $t$.

I am trying to compare
the expected number of mistakes in this algorithm,
which I denote with $F$,
with that of the best-performing expert ($M_\min^t$).
Let $F^t = \sum_{i} (w_i^t m_i^t/W^t)$
be the expected number of mistakes at time $t$.
We know, from linearity of expectation,
that $F = \sum_t F^t$.
By definition, we know the following facts about $W^t$:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  & W^t \geq && \frac{1}{M_\min^t + c} \\
  & W^{t+1} = && \sum_{i} w_i^t \frac{M_i^t+c}{M_i^t+m_i^t+c} 
    & = W^t - \sum_{i.~m_i^t=1} \frac{m_i^t}{M_i^t+m_i^t+c} w_i^t \\
  &&&& \leq W^t - \frac{1}{t+c+1}\sum_{i.~m_i^t=1} m_i^t w_i^t \\
  &&&& = W^t \left(1 - \frac{1}{t+c+1} F^t \right)
\end{alignat*}
By definition, we know $W^0 = N/c$,
where $N$ is the number of experts.
So, we have
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \frac{1}{M_\min^{T+1}+c} 
    & \leq \frac{N}{c} \prod_{t=1}^{T}
      \left(1 - \frac{F^t}{t+c+1} \right) \\
  \implies -\ln(M_\min^{T+1}+c) 
    & \leq \ln\frac{N}{c} + \sum_{t=1}^T
      \ln\left(1 - \frac{F^t}{t+c+1} \right)
\end{alignat*}
We know $\ln{1-z} \leq -z$; so, we obtain
$$ -\ln(M_\min^{T+1}+c) 
   \leq \ln\frac{N}{c} - \sum_{t=1}^T
      \frac{F^t}{t+c+1} $$

What I want to achieve in the end is
an inequality that bounds $F$
(that is, $\sum_t F^t$) from above.
Yet, I cannot see how I can get a non-trivial bound,
using the last inequality.

Can I derive something useful
from the last inequality?
Should I change my previous steps?